# How to I validate form's data in WPF app?

Tags: c#, wpf, validation, xaml

I am trying to learn WPF "the right way"

I was able to create my form using XAML. In the view code, set the `DataContect` using c# to the view model like so

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = new VendorViewModel();
    }
}
```

My XAML code look like this

```
<Window x:Class="Proj1.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">

    <StackPanel Style="{StaticResource Col}">
        <Grid>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions >
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" ></ColumnDefinition>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Style="{StaticResource Col}">

                <TextBlock Text="Name" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="Name" Style="{StaticResource FormControl}"></TextBox>

            </StackPanel>

            <StackPanel Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource Col}">
                <TextBlock Text="Phone Number" Style="{StaticResource FormLabel}"></TextBlock>
                <TextBox x:Name="Phone" Style="{StaticResource FormControl}"></TextBox>
            </StackPanel>

        </Grid>
        </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

However I am not sure how to add data validation and also let the UI know if the request failed due to SQL error or to an invalid entry. I want to be able to make the inputbox red when an error happens and maybe show the error message under the input.

In an ASP.NET MVC 5 framework, we use data Notation to add the validation rules in the ViewModel.But I am not sure how to do this using WPF.

How can I add validation to my form using my view model? Is there a good tutorial that i can use that would help me see how a full CRUD is done in WPF along with validation and data storing into the database?

Comment: It depends how far along the learning curve you are, and what frameworks you are using and how MVVM this is. This questions seems like a bit of a moving target. And your Xaml is already very suspect  This is a good place to start http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/ Once we know you are Implimenting MVVM correctly then we can discuss validation in view models

Comment: Also no there is no validation regime as you have seen with MVC, however there are frameworks that can help, or if its only simple you can roll your own very easily

Comment: There are two interfaces to support Validation in MVVM that do work decently. I can only ever remember hte name of the simpler one: INotifyDataErrorInfo. The complex one supported multiple errors per property. Once you have set a proper MVVM pattern, you validate in the setter. Let the View register the Data Errors. And block the Commands/Actions on having Error Counts > 0. Years ago I wrote a short intro int MVVM, it might help you: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/b1a8bf14-4acd-4d77-9df8-bdb95b02dbe2/lets-talk-about-mvvm?forum=wpf

Comment: @MichaelRandall I am not using any framework. I started a project using Visual Studio "with the build in setup" I did not know that another framework is required to get started.

Comment: No you don't need any other frameworks to get started, everything can be done easily enough, but they are common and it helps to know what we are working with. .. Also its hard to help you as its we don't know how you are plumbing this altogether or if you are even conforming to MVVM in any way. how did you go with that link i suggested or the one  @Christopher suggested

Comment: @MichaelRandall  giving the nice article you shared with me, how would I add validation? Also in the User class the model which would be used by entity framework to interact with the database? Also, where would I do role validation? http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/raj1979/simple-mvvm-pattern-in-wpf/

Answer (score 0):

I have been a little reluctant to answer this question as there are many ways to do it, and it can lead down a rabbit hole. Though i will give you probably the simplest way i can think of in WPF via a `ValidationRule`

**Example**

```
public class SpaceValidationRule : ValidationRule
{

    public override ValidationResult Validate(object value, CultureInfo cultureInfo)
    {
        var str = value as string;
        if(str == null)
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Please enter some text");
        }
        if(!str.Contains(" "))
        {
            return new ValidationResult(false, "Contains Spaces!);
        }
        return new ValidationResult(true, null); 
    }
}
```

**Xaml**

```
<TextBox 
    <TextBox.Text>
        <Binding Path="MyAwesomeVmProperty" UpdateSourceTrigger="PropertyChanged">
            <Binding.ValidationRules>
                <local:SpaceValidationRule />
            </Binding.ValidationRules>
        </Binding>
    </TextBox.Text>
</TextBox>
```

**Additional Resources**

[Data validation in WPF](https://blog.magnusmontin.net/2013/08/26/data-validation-in-wpf/)

[ValidationRule Class](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.validationrule(v=vs.110).aspx)